# Replacing an outlet in a bedroom

Tags: electrical

I have 5 outlets in a room I just replaced one. I want the one to be hot all the time but the others as switched outlets. Should I just cap the red wire on the new receptacle. If I do that will it make the others still switched outlets. Right now all are hot all the time with the switch on and off. I didn’t break the tab on the new receptacle but hooked the red wire up too. Is it just back feeding all the other outlets then.

Comment: Yes, if you have connected red and black together one will feed the other. Wire doesn't care about direction.